# How to make resize event inside content script work?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The resize event doesn't work on content scripts in the Add-on SDK (1.8)
this script: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/142401/latest/

**main.js:**

```
var Widget = require("widget").Widget;
var tabs = require('tabs');
var self = require('self');
var data = self.data;
var PageMod = require('page-mod').PageMod;

exports.main = function() {

    PageMod({
        include: [data.url("thepage.html")],
        contentScriptWhen: 'start',
        contentScriptFile: [data.url('thescript.js')],
        onAttach: function(worker) {
                console.log("attaching...")
        },
    });

    new Widget({
        id: "my-widget-1",
        label: "Widget",
        contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
        onClick: function(event) {
            tabs.open(data.url("thepage.html"));
        }
    });
};
```

**thescript.js**

```
console.log('started')
window.onresize = function(){console.log('resized!!!');}; //not working, never calls
```

How can I make an resize event triggers inside the content script ?

Comment: The thescript.js looks right. Most likely reason it is never called is because there must be an error that occurs prior to the line where it is called. You just need to debug it with Firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally not recommendable to use `window.onfoo` to attach event listeners. There can be an issue if some other code tries to attach an event listener the same way (one event listener will win and you don't know which one), and it [won't work if you access `window` through a wrapper rather than directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCNativeWrapper#Limitations_of_XPCNativeWrapper). So it is always better to use [`addEventListener` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) instead:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  console.log('resized!!!');
}, false);
```

In your case this actually fixes the problem - the event listener fires when the window is resized.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I tried the same thing before, it said window.addEventListener is not a function, that's why I recurred to stackoverflow, now I sound dumb =/
Thank you Wladimir.

Comment: This was the simplest answer to this rather simple topic. Most other answers mix jQuery and a lot of other incidental stuff. +1, and I'm surprised this hasn't received more upvotes.